# Changing a property of a external CSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, external

First of all, sorry for bad english.

Well, I need to change the color property of all parragraphs, using javascript, here's my html&JS code:

```
<body>
<p>Parragraph one</p>
<p>Parragraph two</p>
<button onclick="CE()">change style</button>
</body>

for (var j=0;j<document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length;j++) {
  if(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[j].selectorText='p')
    document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[j].style.color="#FF0000";
}
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
p{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

I tried to change it with this too: `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor="#FF0000"`;
(trying to change the background color, just to see if it works, but only works on Mozilla Firefox)

Comment: Rather than trying to use JS to update the stylesheet itself, why not simply use JS to add a class to your elements, where that class would (obviously) have the desired colour?

Comment: if you're interested in jQuery, then this is so easy using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Make another class with the colors you want, then use jQuery to add and remove the classes as you see fit.

Comment: I don't think he wanted to use jQuery

Comment: Well then he can use http://toddmotto.com/creating-jquery-style-functions-in-javascript-hasclass-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass/ and write the functions manually without jQuery. :-)

Comment: That's great ! I'm keeping this :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using Jquery, you can iterate over all the `<p>` tags and add a css class using javascript. Something like this should work, though I have not tested it.

```
<script>
function CE()
{
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        paragraphs[i].setAttribute("class", "theme")
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.theme{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a new class to your css and loop through all p elements and add the new class:

```
.p-different-color{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
}    

$("p").each(function(index, element) {       // note that the .each() handler has two parameters that can be used also
            $(this).removeClass();              // "this" inside the .each() handler function is the current DOM element in the iteration
            $(this).addClass('p-different-color');  
            });
```